# Moving from pooling to fully connected: logits and labels must have the same first dimension

Tags: tensorflow

I'm starting with tensorflow, and I have some problems that I couldn't solve.

I started with some algorithms to input a batch of images to predict them, but I have some problems with shapes.

GIST: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5140ee46b1036742c26f3b050ec0a7d9

I think the error is on line 53. I'm not sure if n_inputs = 63360 is correct on line 36.

**Probably I need to transform batch of images pooled to fully connected layer.**

The error is: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1,2] and labels shape [2] [[Node:loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlabels=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](dnn/fully_connected_2/BiasAdd, _arg_Placeholder_1_0_1)]]`

But I think that I'm missing some important step.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by mismatched shapes. You can reshape the logits or labels so that their shapes match.

For example:

```
logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1])
xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits))
```